# Keep display active while KVM switched to other PC

Tags: kvm-switch

I appreciate that this maybe quite specific but I wondered if there was any way to keep the display output going (as if I was still using Ubuntu) when I switch KVM to another device? I only have a single monitor and so switching KVM seems to make Ubuntu (correctly I guess) think there is no longer a display device so stops any display being active.

Comment: I suspect this is hardware specific... I have KVM switches were this is achieved easily (*no change/effort*), and others where it required me to make changes... On some KVM switches it was as easy as adding a second mouse to each box; the *second* (USB/PS2) mouse I sat behind each box & it wasn't ever used!  Why that worked I have no idea - but it allowed me to use some KVM switches as I wanted (*alas it did nothing on others*). Either way in my experience it's a hardware issue & not related to the OS.

Comment: Thanks for the info :( I wonder if the ubuntu Server edition may work better as I suspect it would be more suited to being run headless.